# Android - findViewById returns null while trying to set value from Serializable

Tags: android

I cannot figure out how to pass this User class Object. I am simply trying to take input from an editText stored in the first activity and then send it to a textView in another activity. I've done this before, but for some reason, I am wrong here, and I keep getting this error "                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.com.avatar/example.com.avatar.DisplayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference". Can anyone help me out here?

```
//1st Activity
findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
                User user = new User();
                textViewNameLocal = findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                intent.putExtra("USER", user);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

//2nd Activity
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textViewName, textViewEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        textViewName = findViewById(R.id.textViewName); //this was the error, it needs to be below the "setContentView(R.layout.activity_display)".
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("USER");
        textViewName.setText(user.getName().toString);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Serialization in your code.

You are getting the error at:

```
textViewName.setText(user.getName());
```

Because the variable `textViewName` is null.

**Consider assigning its reference to it using `findViewById` only after the call to the method `setContentView`**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
textViewName = findViewById(R.id.textViewName); //call after setContentView

Intent intent = getIntent();
User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("USER");
textViewName.setText(user.getName());
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement your class with Serializable. Let's suppose that this is your entity class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial") //With this annotation we are going to hide compiler warnings
public class User implements Serializable {

    public User(double id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(double id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private double id;
    private String name;
}
```

We are sending the object called `user` from X activity to Y activity. Somewhere in X activity;

```
User obj = new User(4,"Yuvi");
Intent i = new Intent(this, Y.class);
i.putExtra("sampleObject", obj);
startActivity(i);
```

In Y activity we are getting the object.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
User obj = (User)i.getSerializableExtra("sampleObject");
```

That's it.